# Getting Apache Superset deployed on Pythonanywhere

Tags: flask, pythonanywhere, apache-superset

I am trying to figure out how to deploy an instance of [Apache Superset](https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset) as a web app on [Pythonanywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) using uWSGI+nginx.

---

I have installed started a virtual environment on Pythonanywhere and installed and setup Superset following the [instructions on the website](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/). Starting a Superset server on Pythonanywhere seems to work, however I can't find any documentation on how to use Superset together with flask, such that the Superset can be used with uWSGI+nginx as is supported by xxx.pythonanywhere.com.

---

The wsgi file is simple:

```
import sys

project_home = u'/home/tmo/testsite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

from flask_app import app as application
```

From what I can understand, on PythonAnywhere the WSGI side of things is managed by a file per domain in /var/www/you_domain_wsgi.py. It needs to define a variable called application, which is the same as the app in your **init**.py., but I fail to see how any sort of Flask app is deployed when running `superset runserver`. In their documentation, they simply state "*Please refer to the documentation of your preferred technology to set up this Flask WSGI application in a way that works well in your environment.*".

in `/superset/bin/` there is a file called `flask` which contains

```
import re
import sys
from flask.cli import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

But I can't really find anything that could remotely look like a Flask wrapper for Superset.

Is there something fundamental I've misunderstood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

giles from Pythonanywhere [suggested this simple solution](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12584/#id_post_48481):

> ```
> import superset
> from superset import app as application
> ```

which worked instantly. E.g. the whole flask file looks like

```
import sys
import superset

project_home = u'/home/tmo/testsite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

from superset import app as application
```

where only the last line is necessary for superset to run.